# Finding roots in higher order polynomials using binary search

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, roots

I could successfully implement a root finder, by recursively:

- finding the zeroes of the nth derivative
- which gives the extrema of the (n-1)th derivative
- which provides alternating sign values to be used to find the zeroes of the (n-1)th derivative using binary search.

What is the name of this method? The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms) has a paragraph on "Newton's method (and similar derivative-based methods)" that doesn't mention it.

Can it be expanded to support multivariate polynomials? I couldn't find a way to do it by myself, and I couldn't search for it because I couldn't find the name of this method.

Comment: I've used this method. I wish I knew a reference.

Comment: The first steps reminisce of [Sturm sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).